# anyone able to give me an idea what does this error mean in laravel4?

Tags: php, laravel, arguments

I'm just learning laravel4 through youtube videos and learning CRUD The RESTful Way I believe I did everything as the youtube does but somehow I do get this error and I have no idea where to start looking what I did wrong.

Can someone please give me an idea what error I should be looking for?

Thanks in advance ^_^

[image: laravel4 error]

Comment: `Factory::make()` arguments are typehinted as `array`s, so they expecting arrays... Somehow, `string` is getting there. That why this error occured.

Comment: HAL9000 > Thanks a lot found it :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is pretty clear: you're passing a string as the first parameter of a method which expects an array.

I'm guessing we're talking about Validation class here:

```
$validation = Validator::make($array, $rules);
```

where `$array` is the array of  `field => value` pairs you want to validate, and `$rules` is an array of rules you want to apply.

Just an example,

```
$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), 
              array('username' => 'required', 'email' => 'required|email'));
```

Or, more verbose:

```
$fields = array('username' => Input::get('username'), 'email' => Input::get('username'));
$rules = array('username' => 'required', 'email' => 'required|email');

$validation = Validator::make($fields, $rules);
```

It's easily explained in the docs [here](http://laravel.com/docs/validation).

Comment: wow that's a superb guess.....ya I was and typed `$v = Validator::make("$input, Post::$rules");` added " into the make....Thanks for the help~!